# view.getWidth() in Dialog not working

Tags: android, android-view, android-dialog

I want to create square buttons, but because I can't get the width by XML to assign it to button's height, I'm doing it by Java. So I do this:

```
View body = inflater.inflate(R.layout.picker_numeric, null);
Button up = (Button) body.findViewById(R.id.picker_numeric_up);
Log.d(TAG, "" + up.getWidth());
int height = up.getWidth();
up.setHeight(height);
........................
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setView(body)
........................
```

I used `Log.d` to confirm that `getWidth()` returns 0. 
Anyone knows why this happens? I'm out of options.

EDIT:
After what *MKJParekh* and *Simon* said my code is this:

dialogContent.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/picker_numeric_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
android:weightSum="3"
tools:ignore="HardcodedText,UselessParent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/picker_numeric_up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="+" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/picker_numeric_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/picker_numeric_down"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="-" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Method in dialog's creator class:

```
public void equalDimens() {
    up.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
               MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    int height = up.getMeasuredWidth();
    android.util.Log.d("dd", ""+height);
    up.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(height, height));
    down.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(height, height));
}
```

Then in Activity's Class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    createMyDialog();
    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout ) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null); 
    mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
         public void onGlobalLayout() {
            myDialogClass.equalDimens();
         }
    });

    setContentView(mainLayout);
}
```

Without calling `myDialogClass.equalDimens()` I obtain this:
[image]

And calling the method I obtain this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to `measure` your view before you can get height and width of the view.

You can do it like this,here `ll2` is your any view object

```
ll2.measure(
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

int height = ll2.getMeasuredHeight();
int width = ll2.getMeasuredWidth();
```

And after getting the height and width you will need to set them as,

```
ll2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
```

Answer (score 0):

You view is measured and inflated but not yet drawn in onCreate.

You can use (amongst other solutions):

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    // get width here
}
```

If you can't use this, e.g. you have dialog boxes spawned from your activity, try a global layout listener.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     // inflate your main layout here (use RelativeLayout or whatever your root ViewGroup type is
     LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout ) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null); 

     // set a global layout listener which will be called when the layout pass is completed and the view is drawn
     mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
     new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
          public void onGlobalLayout() {
               // measure your views here
          }
     }
 );

 setContentView(mainLayout);
```

}

Comment: Yes, I wanted width = height. Do you know a easier way to do it?

Comment: I don't want to use onWindowFocusChanged because I have more than one Dialog. I could create a method to return the focus only on that Dialog, but is that really needed only to set width = height?

Comment: Well, lots of ways to do it but you have to do it after onCreate.  I posted an easy answer, which doesn't suit your scenario, so I've amended my answer.

Comment: I've tried to use globalLayoutListener, and even put together your solution with @MKJParekh's one but it didn't work either. Maybe the problem is elsewhere but I don't know where. I simply use a LinearLayout and don't use any shape in the buttons. So XML is not the problem ...

Comment: Are you saying that getWidth returns zero in the layout listener?

Comment: I updated my question so it be easier to understand what is going on.

Comment: Still not enough information.  What is getMeasuredWidth returning and what is it set to in the XML?

Comment: Ok so I added the XML code to the question. getMeasuredWidth return 45, it seems to be about 1/3 of the right width as you can see.